# Laravel. Move Js functions from blade to resources/js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

In controller I have

```
 $markers = Marker::all();

 return view('home', ['markers' => $markers]);
```

And In `home.blade` I have next js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        @foreach($markers as $marker)
            var lat = {{$marker->lat}};
            var lng = {{$marker->lng}};
            var id  = {{$marker->id}};
            var position = {lat:lat,lng:lng};
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                id: id
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type    : 'GET',
                    url     : '{{action('MarkerController@getMarkerComments')}}',
                    data:{
                        _token : '{{csrf_token()}}',
                        id     : this.id
                    },
               });
        @endforeach
    });
```

How I can in write way move this code in `resources/js/app.js` and use it in my project like `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`.

Comment: You can use this package https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer to publish `$markers` into js. Then you can move all js that you have on your `home.blade` view, into a dedicated js file.